# filtering grouped pandas dataframe by all records being the same

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to filter a grouped pandas dataframe to groups where all the values in the group are the same.

**reproducible data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                     'value3':[24, 45, 34, 55, 44, 33, 1, 2, 3, 98, 98, 98]})
```

I've tried something like...

```
df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: x.value3 == x.value3.mean())
```

expected output is...

```
   group  value3
0      C      98
1      C      98
2      C      98
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need add `all`

```
df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: (x.value3 == x.value3.mean()).all())
Out[409]: 
   group  value3
9      C      98
10     C      98
11     C      98
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Can you help explain what is happening in the lambda function?

Comment: @MattW. by adding the all, will only return all value equal to the mean of that sub group

Answer (score 3):

You can use nunique as a different method:

```
df.groupby('group').filter(lambda x: x.value3.nunique() == 1)
```

Output:

```
   group  value3
9      C      98
10     C      98
11     C      98
```